# Appengine Memcache issue while using objectify 6.1.1 in Java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm currently in the process of updating an AppEngine Java 8 application to Java 17. For data storage, I'm using Objectify 6.1.1. While everything runs smoothly on my local machine, I've encountered an error upon deployment to AppEngine:

```
Service error in memcache com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache get: exception getting 1 key (_ahsqqEUNfIm9dUJU6HXFPz6YA) ....
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: memcache.Get
```

I've attempted to rectify this by enabling Memcache via the API and services settings, but to no avail. Additionally, I've tried disabling caching, but this hasn't resolved the issue either.

```
ObjectifyService.ofy().cache(false)
                .load()
                .type(Model.class)
                .first()
                .now();
```

Are there any solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the Objectify v6 code uses the `com.google.appengine.api.*` package classes. Those are the legacy appengine API classes that Objectify v5 uses.

My guess is that you have both Objectify v5 and v6 on your classpath. You can only have one or the other.

Comment: I haven't used Objectify v5. And, I also remove the appengine-api-1.0-sdk package. However, I am still getting the same issue. Do you have any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: All I can tell you is that this doesn't have anything to do with Objectify v6, which doesn't touch `com.google.appengine.api.*`. Those classes aren't even available to the v6 build. Look at your project dependency graph and figure out how either an old version of Objectify or some other code that accesses the legacy memcache service is getting pulled into your build. This is a classpath issue.

Comment: I resolved it by adding  <app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis> in appengine-web.xml file

Comment: You have not resolved the classpath issue, which is the root problem. You're still trying to use the legacy memcache API. If this in fact is coming from Objectify, you're using v5, not v6. If you actually have both versions on your classpath, you will have many weird and unpredictable classloader problems going forward. Get your classpath figured out.